# PowerShell: export GPO to a text file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, batch, dump

I'm new to Windows Server, and I'm curious: is there any way to dump group security settings to a text file, using PowerShell or batch files? Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused, in the title you're asking about exporting the GPO to a text file, and then in the question you're asking about exporting group security settings to a text file?

Comment: Needs clarification. Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Powershell **Get-GPOReport** command to export all your GPO settings either to HTML or to XML file.

```
Import-Module GroupPolicy

# Export a specific GPO
Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType Html -Path Default.html
Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType Xml -Path Default.xml

# Export all GPOs
Get-GPOReport -All -ReportType Html -Path All.html
Get-GPOReport -All -ReportType Xml -Path All.xml
```

More information about **Get-GPOReport** usage can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee461057.aspx